# What is the most general/abstract way to think about Tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-analysis, tensors

In their most general and abstract definitions as Mathematical Objects :

- A Scalar is an element of a field used to define Vector Spaces
- A Vector is an element of a Vector Space.

Since a Scalar *is* a Tensor of rank-0 and a Vector *is* a Tensor of rank-1, then what Space are Tensors an element of?

Can you even think of Tensors abstractly as elements of a Mathematical Space?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the answer to this question lies somewhere in Abstract Algebra?

Comment: I never really understand the limit people draw between "abstract algebra" and "linear algebra", but yes I guess. There are *many* levels of comprehension for tensor products, but the most basic are not too complicated.

Comment: well, according to this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebra scalars and vectors already belong to that area (abstract algebra), so it's likely to be a yes. Informally I'd say tensor spaces are quite concrete....

Comment: I´d say in abstract nonsense, i.e. category theory, it´s a universal element in the category of multilinear products

Comment: @PeterMelech no, that would be the tensor product of modules or vector spaces. The OP asks about tensors, which are just elements of that animal.

Comment: @Thomas Ok, wouldn´t it be the most abstract way to think of tensors as elements of "this animal"?

Comment: You ask: can you even think of Tensors abstractly as elements of a Mathematical Space? How else could you think of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Rank one tensors*, on a vector space $V$ over the scalar field $\Bbb F$, are **linear maps** 
$$V\to\Bbb F$$ 
and 
$$V^*\to\Bbb F,$$ 
where $V^*$ is the dual space of $V$.

*Rank two tensors* are **bilinear maps** 
$$V\times V\to\Bbb F,$$
$$V^*\times V\to\Bbb F,$$
$$V^*\times V^*\to\Bbb F.$$

*Rank three tensors* are **trilinear maps** 
$$V\times V\times V\to\Bbb F,$$
$$V^*\times V\times V\to\Bbb F,$$
$$V^*\times V^*\times V\to\Bbb F,$$
$$V^*\times V^*\times V^*\to\Bbb F,$$
and so on.